# Get lambda expression (linq) for query count(1)

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core

For counting a table, tried this:

```
list.Count()
```

That is translated to this query:

```
select count(*) 
from Tutorials 
where (expression)
```

But for optimizing the query, I need:

```
select count(1) 
from Tutorials 
where (expression)
```

Can we create exactly above query in Linq?

I tried with these attempts:

```
dbcontext.Tutorials.Where(expression).Count()

dbcontext.Tutorials.Where(expression).Select(c => c.Id).Count()

dbcontext.Tutorials.Where(expression).Count(c => c.Id > 0)
```

Comment: Depending on your concrete RDBMS used in the background, there's a good chance that `select count(*)` and `select count(1)` are producing the absolutely identical execution plan and are therefore considered **identical** ... (at least this is the case for **SQL Server** - don't know about other RDBMS in detail)

Comment: thank you, so these have same result & performance.

Comment: Yes. `COUNT(*)` by definition counts the number of rows. `COUNT(1)` counts the number of non-null `1` values (`1` is always non-null) if one such value is associated for every row.  The answer is the same and I would be very surprised is any DBMS was not optimized to treat both as the same. I think in the distant past, `COUNT(*)` was not standardized or perhaps not universally supported, so some old-timers still use `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: Even if you write `dbcontext.Tutorials.Where(expression).Select(_ => 1).Count()`, Linq will still generate `Count(*)` because using `Count(1)` does not provide any performance improvements.